# K&R recursive descent parser error

Tags: c

I'm working on K&R Chapter 5.

The book has just introduced a recursive descent parser to illustrate some of the "complicated declarations" found in C. However, the program always reports a syntax error.

For instance, if I run the program as shown below and type `int a;` then hit return I receive the following output:

```
$ ./dcl
int a;
syntax error
a:  int
```

I have also tried redirecting a file with a single int and empty main function, but receive the same error, so don't think it's a '\n' issue.

The next exercise 5-18 asks the reader to "Make dc1 recover from input errors", but I don't believe I have it working correctly yet. I subsequently copied and pasted the code from a PDF of the book, so think it reflects what was printed.

Advice on diagnosis and solution much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXTOKEN 100
#define BUFSIZE 100

enum { NAME, PARENS, BRACKETS };

void dcl(void);
void dirdcl(void);

int bufp = 0; /* next free position in buf */
int gettoken(void);
int tokentype;           /* type of last token */
char token[MAXTOKEN];    /* last token string */
char name[MAXTOKEN];     /* identifier name */
char datatype[MAXTOKEN]; /* data type = char, int, etc. */
char out[1000];
char buf[BUFSIZE]; /* buffer for ungetch */


int main() /* convert declaration to words */
{
     while (gettoken() != EOF) { /* 1st token on line */
      strcpy(datatype, token); /* is the datatype */
      out[0] = '\0';
      dcl(); /* parse rest of line */
      if (tokentype != '\n')
           printf("syntax error\n");
      printf("%s: %s %s\n", name, out, datatype);
     }
     return 0;
}

/* dcl: parse a declarator */
void dcl(void)
{
     int ns;
     for (ns = 0; gettoken() == '*'; ) /* count *'s */
      ns++;
     dirdcl();
     while (ns-- > 0)
      strcat(out, " pointer to");
}

/* dirdcl: parse a direct declarator */
void dirdcl(void)
{
     int type;
     if (tokentype == '(') {
      dcl(); /* ( dcl ) */
      if (tokentype != ')')
           printf("error: missing )\n");
     } else if (tokentype == NAME) /* variable name */
      strcpy(name, token);
     else
      printf("error: expected name or (dcl)\n");
     while ((type=gettoken()) == PARENS || type == BRACKETS)
      if (type == PARENS)
           strcat(out, " function returning");
      else {
           strcat(out, " array");
           strcat(out, token);
           strcat(out, " of");
      }
}

/* return next token */
int gettoken(void)
{
     int c, getch(void);
     void ungetch(int);
     char *p = token;
     while ((c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
      ;
     if (c == '(') {
      if ((c = getch()) == ')') {
           strcpy(token, "()");
           return tokentype = PARENS;
      } else {
           ungetch(c);
           return tokentype = '(';
      }
     } else if (c == '[') {
      for (*p++ = c; (*p++ = getch()) != ']'; )
           ;
      *p = '\0';
      return tokentype = BRACKETS;
     } else if (isalpha(c)) {
      for (*p++ = c; isalnum(c = getch()); )
           *p++ = c;
      *p = '\0';
      ungetch(c);
      return tokentype = NAME;
     } else
      return tokentype = c;
}


/* get a (possibly pushed-back) character */
int getch(void) 
{
     return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

/* push character back on input */
void ungetch(int c) 
{
     if (bufp >= BUFSIZE)
      printf("ungetch: too many characters\n");
     else
      buf[bufp++] = c;
}
```

Comment: Don't enter the semicolon in the input.  Or modify the program to accept a semicolon as the end of a declaration, like newline.  Note that it does not accept multiple declarations on a single line either, so `int a, b` won't be accepted.

Comment: I guess you should not work on a long-outdated resource as the K&R is (latest edition even predates C89, not to mention C99 and C11), unless it's for gaining a historical restrospective on the C language of course.

Comment: What would you recommend instead as a modern alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathan Leffler is correct, the code simply parses the declaration syntax as outlined immediately before the code in the book, not a syntactically correct declaration as you would find in code.